# N-channel mosfet turn constantly on after a while

Tags: mosfet, mosfet-driver, powermosfet

[image]

Hi;

N-channel mosfet (Q4) work fine for couple of time and suddenly turn on constantly.

I changed Q4 multiple of times and each time it work for couple of time and suddenly turn on constantly.

the output of mosfet is connected to a 2.5 amper 12 volt car windshield washer pump and the reason of C11 and R33 is because of water pump noise that cause microcontroller to dont work normal.

What could be the reason of this problem ?

Comment: Is the MOSFET getting hot?  What is the voltage on the gate?  Slow/incomplete turn-on may be frying the device.

Answer (score 7):

You need to prevent back emfs from the washer motor destroying your MOSFET when it deactivates. The normal method is a "reverse" diode in parallel with the motor such as this (equally needed for a BJT as a MOSFET): -

[image]

This suggestion is made assuming that the motor is never operated in reverse - if it is then a slightly different arrangement is needed.

Comment: Thanks, i assumed internal diode of mosfet is enough.but i will test this method and see what happens

Comment: The internal MOSFET diode is not going to work in this configuration.

Comment: i try flyback diod and the result is the same. no change...

Comment: This may sound silly but did you also change the MOSFET because once the MOSFET has been subject to an unclamped back emf, it won't work again. If you did change the MOSFET then what diode did you use?

Comment: yes i use new mosfet every time, and diode is 1n4007

Comment: Well the information in my answer is beyond suspicion i.e. it is the recognized thing to do when protecting output transistors from inductive load flyback voltages so, it then throws doubt on how you have done the "fix" i.e. I am suspicious about how you implemented it. So, please take a photograph and provide a viewing link via IMGUR or a similar site.

Comment: Because you brought up the internal body diode, I want to point out that the diode for protection should be across the load, not the FET. (Andy drew it correctly here, I just want to make sure you notice the difference)

Comment: 1N4007 is probably not fast enough to protect your MOSFET. Try a 1N5817 Schottky.

Comment: @DerStrom8 it will be - the reverse recovery time causes it to remain conducting when going from rapid forward to reverse bias and that is inconsequential here.

Comment: Actually the mosfet is just fine and work correctly, the Q5 pnp transistor is the actual problem. I replace Q5 and it works just fine but after few minute the mosfet stay on constantly and the Q5 is the cause.

Comment: What might be the cause of failure of Q5 ? Is it from my design ?

Comment: Your circuit indicates no reason for Q5 to fail that I can see. Double check what you built and remember what I said about a photograph. You still need the diode by the way.

Comment: image of pcb : https://pasteboard.co/JAPzQw1.jpg

Comment: I can't see anything obvious but where did you mount the flyback diode?

Comment: flyback diode and snubber circuit are directly connected across pump wire because they were not part of original pcb design.

Comment: yet, reason for the problem is not found but the thing that is obvious it might be the soldering or quality of component problem because there is no error in the design still Q5 fail sometimes.